# How does mySQL GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT() Affect Data Output on identical values?

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

**UPDATED EDIT:
Will DISTINCT or GROUP BY arbitrarily use other fields in the query to eliminate duplicates or select the topmost row, or take ORDER BY into consideration in any way?**

I have a monster query where I work with a large number of joined tables, I wish I could post the whole thing but its proprietary so bits and pieces will have to suffice, but here goes a boiled down sample - I am trying to figure out exactly what mySQL is doing when it is grouping and outputting rows based on the below kind-of-query (the real thing is about 2 pages).

Version 1 - designed to eliminate duplicate records of ID2

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
DISTINCT ID1
, ID2
, ID2_Sequence
, DATE1
, DATE2
, <SECRET GUTS OMITTED>
GROUP BY ID2
ORDER BY DATE1 DESC
 *sometimes ORDER BY DATE2 DESC*
```

Version 2 - designed to show all records

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
DISTINCT ID1
, ID2
, ID2_Sequence
, DATE1
, DATE2
, <SECRET GUTS OMITTED>
GROUP BY ID1
ORDER BY DATE1 DESC
*sometimes ORDER BY DATE2 DESC*
```

There are several other joins that are a part of this but I think this is the gist of it. The main issue to contend with and why we eliminate duplicate is that there are one-to-many ID1 to ID2 and ID2s based on another field for the ID2 sequence.

At first examination of the data (there are about 70 cols so hard to pin down what is being filtered how) it looked like it was eliminating the records with older DATE1, but I'm not convinced that is the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`group by` will collapse any rows whose grouped-by fields are identical. `select distinct` is the same as `select distinctrow`, and applies the 'distinct' to the entire row. e.g.

```
field1  field2  field3
1       1       1        <--- row 1
1       1       2        <--- row 2
1       2       3        <--- row 3
1       1       1        <--- row 4, identical to row 1
```

Then do these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM x GROUP BY field1
```

returns a single row, since all rows have the SAME field1 value

```
SELECT * FROM x GROUP BY field1, field2
```

returns 2 rows, since field2 has two different values

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM X
```

returns 3 rows, since row 1 and 4 are identical, you'll get rows 1,2,3

Comment: Did you mean GROUP BY field1, field2 in your second example?

Comment: In addition : if you use GROUP BY you can even add some aggregation functions in select statement / where clause etc. While using distinct does not allow you to do that.

Comment: Thanks, will DISTINCT or GROUP BY arbitrarily use other fields in the query to eliminate duplicates or select the topmost row, or take ORDER BY into consideration in any way?